# iam new to hadoop mapreduce and face a trouble when submit my mapreduce job from windows to the cluster running on linux

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

i am setting up a psudo hadoop mapreduce cluster and hbase, and i want to submit a hbase mapreduce job to the cluster, now the cluster is working well and dependency libs is transmited to the directory /tmp/hadoop-yarn/.../.staging/ under hdfs, but job class itself is not here.
i run my program in idea IDE, when i debug the process of submitting job, i get that the problem point is at

```
public static String findContainingJar(Class<?> clazz) {
  ClassLoader loader = clazz.getClassLoader();
  String classFile = clazz.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class";
  try {
    for(final Enumeration<URL> itr = loader.getResources(classFile);
        itr.hasMoreElements();) {
      final URL url = itr.nextElement();
      //at here the protocol of url is alway 'file', so the next process is 
      //not executed, but i don't know how to slove it
      if ("jar".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
        String toReturn = url.getPath();
        if (toReturn.startsWith("file:")) {
          toReturn = toReturn.substring("file:".length());
        }
        toReturn = URLDecoder.decode(toReturn, "UTF-8");
        return toReturn.replaceAll("!.*$", "");
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  return null;
}
```

when program is run , i got exception

```
Application Overview
User:   root
Name:   testJob
Application Type:   MAPREDUCE
Application Tags:   
YarnApplicationState:   FAILED
Queue:  default
FinalStatus Reported by AM:     FAILED
Started:      20 08:34:56 +0800 2023
Elapsed:    2sec
Tracking URL:   History
Diagnostics:    
Application application_1689669155126_0010 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1689669155126_0010_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://administrator:8088/cluster/app/application_1689669155126_0010Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1689669155126_0010_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /bin/bash:  0 line:fg: no job control
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: /bin/bash: 0 line:fg: no job control
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

here is the output when i run ./bin/hadoop fs -ls -R /tmp/hadoop-yarn

```
drwx------   - root supergroup          0 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup         80 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/job.split
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup         27 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/job.splitmetainfo
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup     120063 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/job.xml
drwx------   - root supergroup          0 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup    1648200 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/guava-11.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup    3479293 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup    1556539 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup     927930 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hbase-client-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup     440700 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hbase-common-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup      32679 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hbase-hadoop-compat-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup    3389801 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hbase-protocol-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup    3461695 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/hbase-server-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup      95975 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup      31532 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/htrace-core-2.04.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup    1199572 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup     533455 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  10 root supergroup     792964 2023-07-20 08:34 /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1689669155126_0010/libjars/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
```

with no logs
No logs available for container container_1689669155126_0010_02_000001

Comment: You need to find the real error from the link - `For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://administrator:8088/cluster/app/application_1689669155126_0010Then, click on links to logs of each attempt`

Comment: i have tried to check logs, actually there is a log dir for this job but no content is loged at all, and checked it on web ui interface only get 'No logs available for container container_1689669155126_0010_02_000001' ,i am really confued and don't know how to take next step, now i am trying to use eclipse remote debug and wish to get a clue

Comment: I've never tried remote debug with Hadoop, because cannot attach to multiple node managers at once (your code will be broken apart to multiple map tasks and reduce tasks, each would use different JVM remote ports, if they run at the same time, on the same machine)... In any case, the code you've shown isn't mapreduce, doesn't log anything, nor uses Hbase, so can you clarify what you're trying to run?